# How to show and hide layout dynamically

Tags: android, layout, dialog, expandable

I want to make layout that expands dynamically, like some kind of menu.
It should look like this

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/845/dialog.jpg/

Step 1:

When I click on `TextView` it should inflate the new layout, remove transparent one, and move text to the left side.

Step 2:

When I click again on `TextView` (it's vertical custom `TextView` btw) it should go back to Step1

I want to put this layout into custom dialog and it should always be on my right side of the screen?

Any ideas how to solve this?
I can do this with two layouts and changing contentView of dialog on every click, but it seems like a very dirty solution. Is there some nice and fancy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is probably just inflating all the Views, set their visibility accordingly, and move the TextView when the user clicks on it.

From the looks of it, it seems like you want to slide between a lot of views by clicking the TextView? If so, you might want to look into something called ViewPager, with a little customization you might be able to archive that.

Answer (score 0):

Create two different layout's mentioned in images like 1) layoutone.xml 2)layouttwo.xml

Now crete on linearlayout in add that layout in your alertdialog. Also add layoutone in that linearlayout by inflating that layout. Now on click of that textview just removeallviews from that linearlayuout & inflate second layout & vice varsa.

Comment: I've done that, it works...but taking references of views over and over again is little bit annoying and unnecessary.